# How do I set the formatting of tinyMCE?

Tags: html, text, format, tinymce

I am using the wysiwyg editor TinyMCE and I have stripped out most of the functions to create a simpler version. However, I need the make the formatting as basic as possible as well, e.g., instead of <p> tags i need to use <br /> tags. Also, I would like it to not convert ' in &rsquo; as I will be using the output in Flash.

The only editing tools still left in it are bold, italic, underline and link/unlink.

Answer (score 2):

You can enforce the use of <br> with the configuration option [force_br_newlines](http://wiki.moxiecode.com/index.php/TinyMCE:Configuration/force_br_newlines) and you can define the encoding with the configuration option [entity_encoding](http://wiki.moxiecode.com/index.php/TinyMCE:Configuration/entity_encoding).

```
entity_encoding: "raw"
force_br_newlines: true,
```